# Discord.io - Bot Status

Tags: bots, statusbar, discord, status, discord.io

I want to set my discord bot status but I'm using `discord.io` no `discord.js` so I can't find some tutorial for me. I tried also watch for discord.js tutorials and try:

```
bot.user.setPresence({ 
  status: 'online', 
  game: { 
    name: '/help' 
  } 
});
```

Error: It crash after start `node bot.js`

**Or:**

```
bot.on('ready', () => {
  bot.user.setGame('/help')
})
```

Error: Parsing error: Unexpected token )

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Could you please post the respective errors in your question? Please edit your question (avoid posting comments to it). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm writting my code with Visual Studio Code. It seems to have a nice autocomplete feature, and by exploring it a little, I was able to find this tip :

> bot.setPresence(
>   options : { idle_since: any; game: {name: string; type: number; url?: string;}}
>   ): void

I'm not sure what *everything* means precisely, but most of it seems to be optional. I was for exemple able to change the bot's playing game with :

```
bot.on('ready', function (evt) {
    bot.setPresence( {game: {name:"/help"}} );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var name = "with the boys. Built by Ayser & Khalid"
var type = 0;
var url = "https://www.twitch.tv/legendarysharkkk";
bot.setPresence({
    game: {
        name,
        type,
        url
}});
```

Comment: list variables first then put in this format. putting a url is mandatory even though it doesnt show. Works for discord.io

Comment: type = 0 (playing)

Comment: type = 1 (streaming)

Comment: type = 2 (listening)

Comment: type = 3 (watching)

Comment: Please edit the answer if you would like to add more details.  Also, a short explanation would help.